# Error while using spring data JPA to fetch from oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

**I am trying to perform regular CRUD operations using Spring data JPA on an oracle database. Here are the details:**

**1. Entity details:**

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Employee {

private long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String emailId;

public Employee() {

}

public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String emailId) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.emailId = emailId;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

@Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@Column(name = "email_address", nullable = false)
public String getEmailId() {
    return emailId;
}
public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
    this.emailId = emailId;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", emailId=" + emailId
+ "]";
}
```

}

**2. Here is my Runner :**

```
    @Component
public class MyRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyRunner.class);

@Autowired
private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

@Override
public void run(String...args) throws Exception {

    employeeRepository.save(new Employee("Ramesh", "Fadatare", "ramesh@gmail.com"));
    employeeRepository.save(new Employee("Tom", "Cruise", "tom@gmail.com"));
    employeeRepository.save(new Employee("John", "Cena", "john@gmail.com"));
    employeeRepository.save(new Employee("tony", "stark", "stark@gmail.com"));

    logger.info("# of employees: {}", employeeRepository.count());

    logger.info("All employees unsorted:");

    Iterable < Employee > employees = employeeRepository.findAll();
    Iterator < Employee > iterator = employees.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        logger.info("{}", iterator.next().toString());
    }

    logger.info("------------------------");

        logger.info("Deleting employee with id 1");
//        employeeRepository.deleteById(1 L);

        logger.info("# of employees: {}", employeeRepository.count());

//        employeeRepository.existsById(2 L);
//        employeeRepository.findById(2 L);
        
    }
}
```

Here is the table thats getting created by name "HTE_EMPLOYEES" :

[image]

**I am getting error due to which its not able to fetch the details or write entries to the table of the repo.Any idea on where is the mistake ? Thanks in advance.**

**Logs :**

2022-10-08T19:22:23.131+05:30 ERROR 51791 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:791) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M5.jar:3.0.0-M5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:772) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M5.jar:3.0.0-M5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M5.jar:3.0.0-M5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1323) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M5.jar:3.0.0-M5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M5.jar:3.0.0-M5]
at com.example.JPAReadFromOracle.Application.main(Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.0-M5.jar:3.0.0-M5]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:257) ~[spring-orm-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233) ~[spring-orm-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550) ~[spring-orm-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:163) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0-M6.jar:3.0.0-M6]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:221) ~[spring-aop-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy100.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.example.JPAReadFromOracle.MyRunner.run(MyRunner.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:788) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M5.jar:3.0.0-M5]
... 10 common frames omitted
**Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet**
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStructure$1.getNextValue(SequenceStructure.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.PooledOptimizer.generate(PooledOptimizer.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:536) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:53) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:735) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:719) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy97.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:610) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0-M6.jar:3.0.0-M6]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0-M6.jar:3.0.0-M6]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0-M6.jar:3.0.0-M6]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0-M6.jar:3.0.0-M6]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0-M6.jar:3.0.0-M6]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0-M6.jar:3.0.0-M6]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0-M6.jar:3.0.0-M6]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:160) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0-M6.jar:3.0.0-M6]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:135) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0-M6.jar:3.0.0-M6]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
... 19 common frames omitted
**Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist**
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:629) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar:21.6.0.0.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:563) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar:21.6.0.0.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1150) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar:21.6.0.0
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:770) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar:21.6.0.0.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:298) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar:21.6.0.0.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:497) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar:21.6.0.0.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:151) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar:21.6.0.0.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:936) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar:21.6.0.0.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.prepareDefineBufferAndExecute(OracleStatement.java:1171) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar:21.6.0.0.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1100) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar:21.6.0.0.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeSQLSelect(OracleStatement.java:1425) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar:21.6.0.0.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1308) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar:21.6.0.0.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3745) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar:21.6.0.0.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3854) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar:21.6.0.0.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1097) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar:21.6.0.0.0]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
... 55 common frames omitted
***Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist***

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:636) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar:21.6.0.0.0]
... 72 common frames omitted

Comment: Probably the sequence named "hibernate_sequence" is missing in your schema.
Better to use "strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE" and have a different sequence per entity.

Comment: @p3consulting Why would that be better?

Comment: One sequence per entity: you control the name, DB schema and application easier to refactor, DB schema easier to reuse in other context, less likely to reach the MAX of the sequence, ... matter of taste if you like...